# Making specific color in R

Tags: r, colors

There is an option in Excel software to define a right color by entering values for Red, Green and Blue to make a new color. How I can do that in R? [image].

Comment: You can use the `rgb()` function. It's not very clear exactly where you want to do this in R. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @ MrFlick , in excel I can make a specific pink colour with Red=236, green=102, blue=150. I am looking for a way to make the same color in R

Comment: You can use `rgb(236, 102, 150, maxColorValue = 255)`

Comment: @ MrFlick, great, thanks so much